# How can I combine 2 lists of data in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 lists of parameter data for multiple different machines.  I am trying to combine the data into a single list, but not all of the parameters are present for all machines.  Is this possible in EXCEL?

**List 1**

[image: List 1]

**List 2**

[image: List 2]

**Combined List:**

[image: Combined List]

Comment: Can 'Machine 3' also exist as one more column in List 2, despite it's already present in List 1? i.e. can a heading co-exist in both the lists at the same time?

Comment: Power Query also is a good choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions.

1. You have only these two tables to manage
2. Little bit of manual table creation is suggested
3. Headings are unique between two lists. i.e. say Machine 4 can exist only either in List 1 or 2 but not both at the same time.

In this example List 1 is in cells C2:F8 and List 2 is at C10:D15

Now first manually create a structure of your table elsewhere. In this example it's created at H2 and thereafter.

Copy Col C (See the second snapshot) Put it in H, remove duplicates and sort it on Col H. Similarly Copy Headers from both Lists one next to other. So you have a structure in place like this.

[image]

Now in I3 put the following formula and drag it down below and across along the length and width of the new table or list.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H3,$C$11:$D$15,MATCH(I$2,$C$10:$D$10,0),FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H3,$C$3:$F$8,MATCH(I$2,$C$2:$F$2,0),FALSE),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an Index/Match.

Lets say the list in the first picture begins on **A1**, and list for the second picture begins on **A9**, then the formula that you would need to enter into cell **E2** would be

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$10:$B$14,MATCH($A2,$A$10:$A$14,0)),"")
```

[image: Here is a picture of the sample you provided]

Comment: To lock cells within Excel you add $ signs at certain places. This allows you to apply formulas to large amounts of cells in an easier manner. For example, **$A1** locks the columns, **A$1** locks the rows, and **$A$1** locks the columns and the rows.

Comment: Thanks for showing a real-life demonstration. I'll give you a +1, even though you missed the bit about creating a combined (merged) list, containing ''Par 3'' and ''Par 51''.